# Why gsub with regex returns different results for single and double quotes?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following text that I try to match and remove backslash and the following numbers:

```
these failings is india\342\200\231s reluctance
```

When I create a string with single quotes and use `\\\d+`, then I get these characters removed, but this text in double quotes returns the same. The following demonstrates what I am trying to say:

```
>> "these failings is india\342\200\231s reluctance".gsub(/\\\d+/, "")
>> "these failings is india\342\200\231s reluctance"
>> 'these failings is india\342\200\231s reluctance'.gsub(/\\\d+/, "")
>> "these failings is indias reluctance"
```

What is the reason and how can I get these characters removed in double quotes as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the regex, your problem is with the string itself. When you say this:

```
"these failings is india\342\200\231s reluctance"
```

The `\342\200\231` is interpreted **by the string** as three bytes in octal and those three bytes are the UTF-8 representation of `’`; the result is that your string really looks like this:

```
"these failings is india’s reluctance"
```

and those three bytes are just one UTF-8 character. If you build the string with single quotes:

```
'these failings is india\342\200\231s reluctance'
```

then the octal escape sequences aren't interpreted as octal byte values at all, they're just the twelve characters:

```
\ 3 4 2 \ 2 0 0 \ 2 3 1
```

that you see in your editor.

If you want to remove that specific apostrophe character then you could use [`tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-tr) thusly:

```
"these failings is india\342\200\231s reluctance".tr("\342\200\231", '')
```

or [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) like this (or all sorts of other ways):

```
"these failings is india\342\200\231s reluctance".gsub("\342\200\231", '')
"these failings is india\342\200\231s reluctance".gsub(/\342\200\231/, '')
```

Note that regex literals supply a double quoted string context so the `\nnn` will be interpreted just like they are in a double quoted string.

You might want to look into your encoding settings front to back to make sure everything (including your terminal and editor) is set up to use UTF-8. That would have made the problem clearer to you.